# The type TabActivity is deprecated when i use TabActivity android

Tags: java, android, tabactivity, android-actionbaractivity

In my android application I want to use `TabHost` to change activities using tabs and below is my `.xaml.` page code where i set `tab` control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TabHost 
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hakslogin.LoginSuccess">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hakslogin.LoginSuccess" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_backlogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_backlogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:text="Login" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_childform"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_backlogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Child Form" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_childform"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="#003EFF"
        android:text="Child" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And below is my activity:

```
package com.example.hakslogin;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class LoginSuccess extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btn_backlogin;
    Button btn_child;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_success);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, AddChildActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Add Child")
          .setIndicator("", null)
          .setContent(intentAndroid);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, AddItemActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Add Item")
          .setIndicator("Add Item", null)
          .setContent(intentApple);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        Intent intentWindows = new Intent().setClass(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Question")
          .setIndicator("", null)
          .setContent(intentWindows);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

But i am getting below error at this line `TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();` :

```
The method getTabHost() is undefined for the type LoginSuccess
```

For resolving this issue I put like below:

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
public class LoginSuccess extends TabActivity{ //ActionBarActivity {
```

the above error is remove, but i am getting another error

```
The type TabActivity is deprecated
```

How can I resolve this issue, kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you are getting an warning not an error. You can try with Fragment. It would support

Comment: I am new, kindly post an example.